Sequence Diagram Advice on how Control and UI works

I'm creating a sequence diagram for a school assignment and I'm unsure about a specific aspect. The Control (CTL) already knows about aRental, so I was thinking that the UI might not need to send it to the CTL again so I did it this way. However, I'm not sure if the self-message from the UI is appropriate in this case. I'm  wondering how the UI will know when the CTL has finished its function to display the message.
I tried searching online but couldn't really find any advice on forums for similar questions

Your screenshot is incomplete. It does not name the lifelines.

Add the complete diagram or part of the diagram with all the information. Cannot get the context correctly.

We can deduce from your diagram that the leftmost lifeline is the UI, since it receives a display message. Likewise, we can deduce that the middle lifeline is the control, because it instructs other to do things.
Fist things first: it would be nice in future to provide extracts of sesuence diagrams with the head of each line, to avoid unnecessary inferences and potential misundertandings.
To your current diagram, something is in any case missing. Because the opt does not mean that suddenly all lifelines know what thzy have to do. One lifelines makes the choice (in principle it's the one that is crossed by the condition, here the UI, which makes sense if the choice is the result of a user interaction.  This one has to inform the others with the right messages that they have to do something. So even if there is no need to pass again the aRenderer because it is something known, some message need to be passed from UI to CTL to tell it it should start the operetions needed for restarting.
